# Запятая перед "плюс"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение, например, такого толка: "Я сегодня на работе(,) плюс вечером у меня дела". Нужна ли тут запятая перед "плюсом"?
Спасибо

Comment: коммунизм = советская_власть + электрификация_всей_страны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужна. Это сложносочиненное предложение. Хоть там "и", хоть "а", хоть "плюс"!

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, здесь слово "плюс" употребляется в значении союза "и", поэтому запятая нужна, так как это сложносочиненное предложение. Однако сама фраза с "плюс" режет слух.